# Aspherical manifold and non-positive curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

If the fundamental group of a smooth closed aspherical manifold is a hyperbolic group, does that manifold admit a metric with non-positive sectional curvature?

If not, what's the obstruction to admitting a metric of non-positive curvature?

Here we are all talking about smooth closed manifold and the curvature are sectional curvature. Aspherical manifold are the maniflod which's universal covering is contractable.

We know that any manifold with a metric of non-positive curvature is aspherical by the Cartan-Hadamard theorem, and when in addition the manifold is negatively curved, then the fundamental group is a hyperbolic group in the context of Gromov. I am curious about the converse.

By the way, does there exist an aspherical manifold which admits a metric with non-negative sectional curvature?

Comment: It is not true that closed nonpositively curved manifolds have hyperbolic fundamental groups - one needs negative curvature for that. There are many examples of the type you want, see section 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4235 for a survey.

Comment: @Igor the question whether hyperbolic $\pi_1$ and aspherical implies the existence of a non-positively curved Riemannian metric is a reasonable question. It's a big question whether hyperbolic groups are all CAT(0).

Comment: @YCor: the question is reasonable and the answer is known, e.g., there are locally $CAT(-1)$ closed manifolds that are not homotopy equivalent to closed smooth manifolds (see section 2.1 in the paper I linked above). One can ask a number of questions of this type and some of them are still open, but again the paper linked above surveys what is known.

Comment: @IanAgol: actually I was answering to Yves, who I thought did not assume smoothness. I think the smooth example can be also constructed. Davis-Januszkiewicz in [Hyperbolization of polyhedra, J. Diff. Geom. 34 (1991), 347--388], https://people.math.osu.edu/davis.12/old_papers/djJDG.pdf, in theorem 5b.1 constructed a closed $CAT(0)$ manifold whose universal cover is not simply-connected at infinity and hence it admits no Riemannian nonpositively curved metric. Apply strict hyperbolization to their example. I think their proof that the manifold is not simply-connected at infinity still holds.

Comment: (cont) I did not check the details though that their proof can be modified to hold, which is why I am NOT posting this as an answer,

Comment: Jialong: you can easily fix the bug instead (just remove the 4th paragraph, or add "when in addition the manifold is compact and negatively curved").

Comment: Thank you all!  By the way,  the question- "does there exist an aspherical manifold which admits a metric with non-negative sectional curvature?"   is a stuip question or not?

Comment: @JialongDeng: flat torus. Less trivially, any nonnegatively curved closed aspherical manifold is flat (i.e. admits a metric of zero sectional curvature.

Comment: I've deleted my answer referring to Davis-Jaunszkiewicz, since Misha Kapovich pointed out that there was an error in the paper. This may be fixed by a construction in Charney-Davis, but this needs to be checked. I might check with one of them who are both here at MSRI now.

Comment: This may be naive, but I think the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem and a theorem of Stallings should be relevant.

The Cartan-Hadamard Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem says that if an complete (which all closed manifolds are), Riemannian manifold has non-positive sectional curvature at each point, then its universal cover is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. (cont)

Comment: The theorem of Stallings https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_at_infinity says that for n ≥ 5, a contractible n-manifold is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ precisely when it is simply connected at infinity.

So, the universal cover not being simply connected at infinity appears to be the obstruction for which you are looking. See this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986451/example-of-contractible-open-manifold-that-is-not-mathbbrn-varieties for constructing them. (cont)

Comment: Also, to answer the question in your last paragraph, look up Bieberbach group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group#Bieberbach.27s_theorems These are all the fundamental groups of closed, ashperical manifolds with 0 sectional curvature everywhere whose universal covers are isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n$. The Klein bottle is the other example in dimension 2.

Comment: @JeffreyRolland, is there a relationship between the fundamental group and the obstruction? Is it obviously  the aspherical manifold  which the obstruction vanish support nonpositive curvature?